# How to add Organisations to LDAP via LDIF?

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldif

I want to initially add a couple of organisations. So I created an `organisations.ldif` in order to add them via

```
ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -W -f organisations.ldif
```

My file looks like this

```
dn: dc=example,dc=com
o: org1
objectClass: top
objectClass: organization
description: Organisational container for #1

dn: dc=example,dc=com
o: org2
objectClass: top
objectClass: organization
description: Organisational container for #2
```

But I get the error

```
adding new entry "dc=example,dc=com"
ldap_add: Object class violation (65)
        additional info: attribute 'dc' not allowed
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Maybe a result of your redacting, but you're adding the same dn twice: `dn: dc=example,dc=com` which likely to fail

Comment: I thought that line is telling into what directory the new entry goes. What would I have to change into? `dn: o=org1,dc=example,dc=com`?

Answer (score 1):

The DN (or "distinguished name") of an LDAP entry isn't "the directory into which this entry goes", it is like the primary key of a database record -- it needs to be unique.

In each case, the DN for the entry should include the value of the `o` attribute, as you described in your comment:

```
dn: o=org1,dc=example,dc=com
o: org1
objectClass: top
objectClass: organization
description: Organisational container for #1

dn: o=org2,dc=example,dc=com
o: org2
objectClass: top
objectClass: organization
description: Organisational container for #2
```

Yes, it unnecessarily duplicates information.  Welcome to LDAP, where everything you know about databases comes to die.

Comment: Throws error `ldap_add: No such object (32)`. That's why I thought I need to declare the `dn` as the "parent item"...

Comment: Do the parent DNs not already exist?

Comment: Yes, it does! `dc=example,dc=com` exists!

Comment: Well... that's weird.